# React-Native-Sound download and playing audio locally doesn't work

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have tried using the absolute path and relative path, it still doesn't play on ios.
these audio files are downloaded using react-native-fetch-blob and locally played.

[UPDATE]: I didn't find a solution for this, however, I got it working by downgrading react-native-sound from 0.10.2 to 0.7.3. I would ideally wish to use the latest version

```
let dirs = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs;
    const basePath = dirs.DocumentDir + "/" + state.app.currentTour._id.toString()
    // let audioPath = basePath + "/" + state.tour.currentAudio;
    let audioPath = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? state.tour.currentAudio : basePath + "/" + state.tour.currentAudio;
    let pathConstant = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? `${Sound.DOCUMENT}/${state.app.currentTour._id.toString()}` : '';

    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('Values', audioPath, pathConstant);
        var track = new Sound(audioPath, pathConstant, (error) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log('errorrrrr', error);
                return;
            }
        });

        setTimeout(() => {
            if (this.state.mounted)
                this.setState({ track })
        }, 150);
    }, 150);
```

[image: error i get]